# Overwrite qty of simple product and variation product in the cart, if they are added in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am the new developer to make the Woocommerce website. I found this useful code in another post. It works to overwrite the stock under product id.

If I have two variation products under the same product id, it will delete all the variation product under same product id in the cart. How can I amend the following code?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 1, 3);
function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    
    $already_in_cart = false;
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ){
        // Check if the item is already is in cart.
        if( $item['product_id'] == $product_id ){
            $already_in_cart = true;
            $existing_product_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $already_in_cart  ){
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($existing_product_key);
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
```

For Example:

Cart

1. Product A (Blue) x 1 qty
2. Product A (Red)  x 1 qty

What I want is if I try to add 2 qty of Product A (Blue), the cart will only overwrite the quantity of Product A (Blue) and keep the quantity of Product A (Red) remain unchanged.